# Multiply operation on columns in group by query in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I came across of using group by at
[Summarizing/aggregating a Scala Slick object into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854671/summarizing-aggregating-a-scala-slick-object-into-another)

Want to take it bit further by multiplying two or more columns (_.countA*_countB) before applying sum function as shown below, but it returns an error "Expected a collection type, found {s2:Int/Number(10....". Any suggestions to handle such scenario.

```
        Query(Things).filter(_.date > date).groupBy(x => (x.labelOne, x.labelTwo)).map
       {
        case ((labelOne, labelTwo), things) => {
                   (labelOne, labelTwo, things.map(_.countA*_.countB).sum)
        }
       }.run.map(SummarizedThing.tupled)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Also posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/Iq6GaslpSNc  Please cross-link topics in the future, if you post the same topic on Stack Overflow and the Slick mailing list. It will help everyone in the community to find answers easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able do to do this in the following way:

Outside your query define the operation

```
//multiplication operator 
val multiply = SimpleBinaryOperator.apply[Int]("*")
```

Make sure that the type (Int) matches the values of your columns and the operator symbol matches the operator that is used in our SQL database language.

Now you should be able to use

```
things.map{case (thingA,thingB) => multiply(thingA, thingB)}.sum
```

To do what you want.

See also: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#user-defined-functions-and-types

Apparently arithmetic cannot be performed within a groupBy due to a bug. You can work around this by wrapping your query in another query:

```
(for{
  product <- (for{
    intA <- A
    intB <- B
  } yield multiply(intA,intB))
} yield product).groupby(...).map(...)
```

Comment: I tried as suggested but I believe this only works on TableQuery object not inside group by, found this bug in slick (https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/511), also see link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/Ppf1QOv1b58

Comment: Perhaps you can work around this by wrapping your query inside another query.